# Gallery Iteration

Tags: php, image, iteration, gallery

I'm working on an image gallery that looks up all of the images that I have uploaded, and allows me to display them 5 at a time on a single page.  The problem is, i'm unsure about how to approach this.

I have $_GET['max'], which is supposed to be the top most image to be displayed.  $min would be $_GET['max'] - 5.  In the event that the user manually enters a number here, I want to set $min to the next number down that's easily divisible by 5, from $REAL_MAX, which is the total number of images that have been uploaded.

How would I go about going through this cycle?  I'm relatively new to coding, and I am attending classes on mathematics and logic to help me through some of this stuff.

Comment: are your image URL's in a mysql table? Or are you simply scanning a directory? Your method seems slightly convoluted from what I can gather.

Comment: Ah, yes.  they're in a mysql table and returned to $result[$current_iteration]

So, I am currently tryin to reference the image as such:

$min = $_GET['max'] - 5;
while ($_GET['max'] > $min)
{
 do whatever...
 $min++
}

my problem is getting $min to be the nearest value below $REAL_MAX divisible by 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
$min = $max - ($max%5) ;
```

Example:
User gives :**$max = 53** then **$min = 50**

The *%*-sign is the modulus operator giving the remainder of $max divided by 5